# Sort: How to treat special character greater than alphabetical in Python 2?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, sorting

Currently Python `sort()` and `sorted()` gives me this:

```
>>> sorted(a, reverse=True, key=lambda s: re.sub('[\[\]]', '', s).lower())
[u'Category123', u'[Cat@123]', u'CAT']
```

But I need:

```
[u'[Cat@123]', u'Category123', u'CAT']
```

I want characters like: `!@#$%^&*` can be sorted as bigger than alphabetical chars.
Thanks.

**EDIT:**
Aside from the accepted answer, I figured out this would solve my problem:

```
>>> sorted(a, reverse=True, key=lambda s:s.upper())
[u'[Cat@123]', u'Category123', u'CAT']
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Return two values from the `key` function, first one is going to be boolean checking whether any of the special characters exists in the string or not and second one the substituted string itself.

```
>>> def func(s):
    subbed = re.sub('[\[\]]', '', s).lower()
    return any(c in '!@#$%^&*' for c in s), subbed
...
>>> lst = [u'Category123', u'[Cat@123]', u'CAT']
>>> sorted(lst, reverse=True, key=func)
[u'[Cat@123]', u'Category123', u'CAT']
```

So, essentially we are sorting something like this:

```
>>> new_lst = [(False, 'category123'), (True, 'cat@123'), (False, 'cat')]
>>> sorted(new_lst, reverse=True)
[(True, 'cat@123'), (False, 'category123'), (False, 'cat')]
```

Comment: great, also i figured out that using `sorted(a, reverse=True, key=lambda s:s.upper())` would solve the problem, not sure why it happened with `s.lower()`